# Is there any rule of silent initial letters in English?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, silent-letters

Mostly we some times uses silent words like knife, knock, knee etc i want to know is there any law in english please also inform me why these are silent? I am a new english language learner.

Comment: Law part is not available in last questions please check those questions before to mark it duplicate.

Comment: This question concerns silent letters at the beginning of a word and not silent letters in general as in lamb (at the end of a word) or the interior of a word. And I think the question asks for a general rule - that is it concerns common words that occur often, and not rarest exotic and academic words in rarest disciplines. I have googled and found nothing really useful and the links here treat silent letters in general. So I think "marked as duplicate" is wrong and the question should be answered.